# Selecting pair of edges in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, topology, select

Given a mesh geometry consisting of edges, I want to select the pairs of adjacent edges for each vertex.

[image]

For vertex a there is only 1 pair [1,2]:

[image]

For vertex b there are 4 pairs [1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,1]:

[image]

For vertex c there are 3 pairs [1,2],[2,3],[3,1]:

[image]

So how do I select these edges such that the output geometry consists of the above-mentioned pairs?

I am guessing this will be done with edges of vertex or mesh topology nodes but I  need help.

Thanks.

Comment: In a view projected on a plane, it is clear, which pairs of edges to select. But what, if there were another edge vertical or maybe only nearly vertical to this plane? Which pairs of edges should be selected then - according to which rules?

Comment: @AndréZmuda this geometry will be a base for the road network so the images I shared are of the intersections. So the edges cannot be vertical. Even if there is some contour we can be sure the edges have different x and y locations.